# less.css sharing variables across files

Tags: less

I am using less.css to simplify my css styling.
I'd like to declare a varaible in one less file and share its usage across my many less files. Is this possible? For example:

**english.less**

> @languageFloat: left;

**chart.less**

```css
div#footer a.web
{   
    display: block;
    float: @languageFloat;
    color: #cccccc;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The best way to do this is to `@import` your LESS file with all your variables in it. Here's the syntax for the `@import` keyword:

```css
// For LESS file includes,
@import "lib.less";
// or
@import "lib"; // infers the .less extension

// and for plain CSS includes which are added but not parsed by LESS
@import "style.css";
```

This works especially well if you serve CSS files to your users (as opposed to the in-browser less.js parsing) because the `@import` statement will compound your LESS and CSS files into one single CSS file. Maybe you can consider having one controller LESS file that includes your variables, then your other LESS and CSS files so that the end result is one single file you serve to the browser.

I imagine it would be something simple like this:

```css
// Controller.less
@import "english.less";
@import "chart.less";
```

Comment: interesting, though I need to share a conditional css file, english can be replaced with German,  Russian etc. Can I import css libraries conditionally?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't understand that problem from your initial question. LESS has no conditional statements (yet), so you have to think declaratively. Make an `englishContainer.less` file that imports `english.less` and `chart.less`, then a `germanContainer.less` file that imports `german.less` and `chart.less`, etc, that's probably the way to do it.