# How to define global variables in css

Tags: html, css

I want to define global variables in one css file and use the variables in other css files.

Is this possible?

**Global.css**:

```
:root {
    --main-color: #192100;
    --main-background: #89b66b;
}

html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: var(--main-color);
}
```

**SomeFile.css**:

```
.some-rule {
    display: table;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 4px solid var(--main-color);
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: var(--main-color);
}
```

**Html**: (*Global.css if referenced before SomeFile.css*)

```
<link href="Global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="SomeFile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: no can do. you need a preprocessor like [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [less](http://lesscss.org/) to achieve such a thing

Comment: recently i came across http://nicolasgallagher.com/custom-css-preprocessing/

Comment: Wait for CSS4 or use sass

Comment: Why not just have a class of root that you just add to elements you want to have it on?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with CSS. Try A CSS Preprocessor like [Less](http://lesscss.org/features/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

[less.css sharing variables across files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756969/less-css-sharing-variables-across-files)

[SASS - use variables across multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598996/sass-use-variables-across-multiple-files)

Comment: Ended up using @import for now. But I'll read more about Less and probably use that in the future

Comment: @SteinTheRuler How did you use `@import` for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CSS itself doesn't use variables. However, you can use another language like SASS or LESS

Comment: True, but check the browser compatibility table. You really don't want to use this just yet